# How to convert a link-local address to global address in Contiki

Tags: c, contiki

I want to convert global address to link level address (or even if it is possible to do the reverse) I have the following function in `uip6.c` file. I want to convert either `rep` (where `rep` gives me lladdress with prefix something like `fe80`) to `srcaddr` (where `srcaddr` gives me global addr with prefix something like `aaaa`) or vice versa.

```
void
cmpr_addr(void)
{
  uip_ds6_route_t *rep;

  rep = uip_ds6_route_lookup(&UIP_IP_BUF->srcipaddr);
  printf("nexthop: ");
  PRINT6ADDR(uip_ds6_route_nexthop(rep));
  printf("\n ");

  printf("srcaddr: ");
  PRINT6ADDR(&UIP_IP_BUF->srcipaddr);
  printf("\n ");   
}
```

I checked earlier that there is no built-in function that can do it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. There is no relationship between a device's link-local address and any public addresses it may have -- they're obtained in completely different ways.

Comment: still i can exclude prefix and compare rest part of address right? i want to know how can i proceed with that

Comment: No. Addresses assigned by a DHCPv6 server, or by SLAAC with privacy extensions (RFC4941), will be completely different from link-local addresses.

Comment: I guess you didnt get my question i just have to compare the two addresses ( i am not considering any privacy ) for instance, if one address is fe80::212.7402.2.202 and other is aaaa::212.7402.2.202. now just prefix are different. how can I exclude prefix and then check rest of address.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. That sort of relationship between addresses is not normal, and you should not expect it. For most devices, on most networks, the link-local address will not be similar to the address(es) it uses to communicate with the outside world.

Comment: @duskwuff Privacy extension is not common on deeply embedded devices. Contiki does not have probably this feature. It could make sense to mask prefix and compare rest of address on such environment.

Comment: @j123b567 Perhaps not on the embedded devices themselves, but what about other devices on the network?

Comment: @duskwuff It depends on the environment OP is using. I agree with you that it is bad idea to do this conversion in general, but there are some situations where it can make sense in some controlled environment.

Comment: This question is Contiki specific, therefore (even though badly worded) valid; I agree with j123b567 that you reasoning does not apply here.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
uip_ds6_route_t *rep;

uip_ipaddr_t copy;

uip_ipaddr_copy(&copy, &UIP_IP_BUF->srcipaddr);
rep = uip_ds6_route_lookup(&UIP_IP_BUF->srcipaddr);
printf("nexthop: ");
PRINT6ADDR(uip_ds6_route_nexthop(rep));
printf("\n ");

printf("srcaddr: ");
copy.u8[0]=0xfe;
copy.u8[1]=0x80;

//copy.u16[0]=0xfe80;
PRINT6ADDR(&copy);
printf("\n ");

if (uip_ipaddr_cmp(&copy, uip_ds6_route_nexthop(rep)))
printf("\nYes Child Node");
else
printf("\nNo Child Node");
```